# Error : Operator is not overloaded

Tags: validation, syntax, error-handling, pascal, pascalscript

I've created a simple block of code using Free Pascal to validate an  ID number such as Abc123 being input.

When I try to run the program I get an error saying, "Operator is not overloaded" at the points where it says,

```
 IF not (Ucase in Upper) or (Lcase in Lower) or (Num in Int) then
```

Specifically where the "in" appears.
Does anyone have any idea why the error occurs and what I can do to solve it?

Thanks!

```
Program CheckChar;

VAR
UserID, LCase, UCase, Num : String;
readkey : char;
L  : Integer;


CONST
Upper = ['A'..'Z'];
Lower = ['a'..'z'];
Int   = ['0'..'9'];

Begin
Write('Enter UserID ');Readln(UserID);
Ucase := Copy(UserID,1,1);
LCase := Copy(UserID,2,1);
Num   := Copy(UserID,3,2);
L     := Length(UserID);

  While L = 6 Do
  Begin
    IF not (Ucase in Upper) or (Lcase in Lower) or (Num in Int) then
    Begin
    Writeln('Invalid Input');
    End;
 Else
   Writeln('Input is valid');

  End;

 readln(readkey);
 End.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`in` is used to test the presence of an element in a set. Here you set is a set of char, so the element to test must also be a char. In your sample the elements you tested were some strings (`UCase`, `LCase` and `Num`) which caused the error message.

You have to use a slice of `Ucase` and `LCase` of length one or you can also directly take a single character (`astring[index]`) instead of copying with `Copy`.

Also your `while` loop is totally useless. You have to test only 6 characters so let's unroll the loop instead of puting some complexity while obsvioulsy you just start learning.

Finally, one way to write your checker correctly is so:

```
Program CheckChar;
var
  UserID  : string;
  readkey : char;
  L  : Integer;
  invalid: boolean;

const
  Upper = ['A'..'Z'];
  Lower = ['a'..'z'];
  Int   = ['0'..'9'];

begin
  Write('Enter UserID ');
  Readln(UserID);
  L := length(UserId);

  if L <> 6 then invalid := true
  else
  begin
    invalid :=  not (UserID[1] in Upper) or // take a single char, usable with in
                not (UserID[2] in Lower) or // ditto
                not (UserID[3] in Lower) or // ditto
                not (UserID[4] in Int) or // ditto
                not (UserID[5] in Int) or // ditto
                not (UserID[6] in Int); // ditto
  end;

  if invalid then
    Writeln('Invalid Input')
  else
   Writeln('Input is valid');

 readln(readkey);
end.
```

Comment: Oh...I was not too sure of how the operator, "in" works. The reason why I included the while loop was to check the length before anything else but now I see that it is indeed redundant.  Thanks a lot!